# How to call REPLACE with CLOB (without exceeding 32K)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Oracle 11g has certainly improved usability of CLOBs, having overloaded most of the string functions so they now work natively with CLOBs.

However, a colleague was getting this error from his code:

```
ORA-22828: input pattern or replacement parameters exceed 32K size limit
22828. 00000 -  "input pattern or replacement parameters exceed 32K size limit"
*Cause:    Value provided for the pattern or replacement string in the form of
           VARCHAR2 or CLOB for LOB SQL functions exceeded the 32K size limit.
*Action:   Use a shorter pattern or process a long pattern string in multiple
           passes.
```

This only occurred when the third parameter to `replace` was a CLOB with more than 32k characters.

(Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production)

Test case:

```
declare
  v2 varchar2(32767);
  cl_small clob;
  cl_big clob;
  cl_big2 clob;
begin
  v2 := rpad('x', 32767, 'x');
  dbms_output.put_line('v2:' || length(v2));
  cl_small := v2;
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_small:' || length(cl_small));
  cl_big := v2 || 'y' || v2;
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_big[1]:' || length(cl_big));
  cl_big2 := replace(cl_big, 'y', cl_small);
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_big[2]:' || length(cl_big2));
  cl_big2 := replace(cl_big, 'y', cl_big); 
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_big[3]:' || length(cl_big2));
end;
/
```

Results:

```
v2:32767
cl_small:32767
cl_big[1]:65535
cl_big[2]:98301
ORA-22828: input pattern or replacement parameters exceed 32K size limit
```

This seems at odds with the docs which imply that the replacement string may be a CLOB - I would have thought this *should* imply that any CLOB would be allowed, not just those that happen to be <32K: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a rough first draft for a function that will do the job with certain limitations, it hasn't been very well tested yet:

```
function replace_with_clob
  (i_source in clob
  ,i_search in varchar2
  ,i_replace in clob
  ) return clob is
  l_pos pls_integer;
begin
  l_pos := instr(i_source, i_search);
  if l_pos > 0 then
    return substr(i_source, 1, l_pos-1)
        || i_replace
        || substr(i_source, l_pos+length(i_search));
  end if;
  return i_source;
end replace_with_clob;
```

It only does a single replace on the first instance of the search term.

```
declare
  v2 varchar2(32767);
  cl_small clob;
  cl_big clob;
  cl_big2 clob;
begin
  v2 := rpad('x', 32767, 'x');
  dbms_output.put_line('v2:' || length(v2));
  cl_small := v2;
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_small:' || length(cl_small));
  cl_big := v2 || 'y' || v2;
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_big[1]:' || length(cl_big));
  cl_big2 := replace(cl_big, 'y', cl_small);
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_big[2]:' || length(cl_big2));
  cl_big2 := replace_with_clob(cl_big, 'y', cl_big); 
  dbms_output.put_line('cl_big[3]:' || length(cl_big2));
end;
/

v2:32767
cl_small:32767
cl_big[1]:65535
cl_big[2]:98301
cl_big[3]:131069
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to handle `CLOB` values of any length:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb7d7c/1)

```
CREATE FUNCTION lob_replace(
  i_lob    IN clob, 
  i_what   IN varchar2, 
  i_with   IN clob,
  i_offset IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  i_nth    IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1
) RETURN CLOB
AS
  o_lob  CLOB;
  n      PLS_INTEGER;
  l_lob  PLS_INTEGER;
  l_what PLS_INTEGER;
  l_with PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF   i_lob IS NULL
    OR i_what IS NULL
    OR i_offset < 1
    OR i_offset > DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE
    OR i_nth < 1
    OR i_nth > DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE
  THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  n      := NVL( DBMS_LOB.INSTR( i_lob, i_what, i_offset, i_nth ), 0 );
  l_lob  := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( i_lob );
  l_what := LENGTH( i_what );
  l_with := NVL( DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( i_with ), 0 );

  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( o_lob, FALSE );
  IF n > 0 THEN
    IF n > 1 THEN
      DBMS_LOB.COPY( o_lob, i_lob, n-1, 1, 1 );
    END IF;

    IF l_with > 0 THEN
      DBMS_LOB.APPEND( o_lob, i_with ); 
    END IF;

    IF n + l_what <= l_lob THEN
      DBMS_LOB.COPY( o_lob, i_lob, l_lob - n - l_what + 1, n + l_with, n + l_what );
    END IF;
  ELSE
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND( o_lob, i_lob );
  END IF;
  RETURN o_lob;
END; 
/
```

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value clob)
/

CREATE TABLE replacements ( str VARCHAR2(4000), repl CLOB )
/

DECLARE
  str VARCHAR2(4000) := 'value';
  r   CLOB;
  c1l CLOB;
  c1m CLOB;
  c1r CLOB;
  c2l CLOB;
  c2m CLOB;
  c2r CLOB;
  c3l CLOB;
  c3m CLOB;
  c3r CLOB;
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( r, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c1l, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c1m, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c1r, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c2l, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c2m, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c2r, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c3l, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c3m, FALSE );
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c3r, FALSE );
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( r, 4000, RPAD( 'y', 4000, 'y' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C1m, 20, RPAD( 'x', 20, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C1r, 40, RPAD( 'x', 40, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C2m, 200, RPAD( 'x', 200, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C2r, 400, RPAD( 'x', 400, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C3m, 2000, RPAD( 'x', 2000, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C3r, 4000, RPAD( 'x', 4000, 'x' ) );
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c1l, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c1m, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c1r, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c2l, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c2m, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c2r, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c3l, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c3m, 5, str );
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c3r, 5, str );
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C1l, 40, RPAD( 'x', 40, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C1m, 20, RPAD( 'x', 20, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C2l, 400, RPAD( 'x', 400, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C2m, 200, RPAD( 'x', 200, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C3l, 4000, RPAD( 'x', 4000, 'x' ) );
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( C3m, 2000, RPAD( 'x', 2000, 'x' ) );
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( NULL );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( EMPTY_CLOB() );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( '0123456789' );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( str );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c1l );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c1m );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c1r );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c2l );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c2m );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c2r );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c3l );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c3m );
  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( c3r );
  INSERT INTO replacements VALUES ( str, r );
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( value )
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb7d7c/1/0)**:

```
| DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(VALUE) |
|---------------------------|
|                    (null) |
|                         0 |
|                        10 |
|                         5 |
|                       405 |
|                       405 |
|                       405 |
|                      4005 |
|                      4005 |
|                      4005 |
|                     40005 |
|                     40005 |
|                     40005 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET value = LOB_REPLACE(
              value,
              ( SELECT str FROM replacements ),
              ( SELECT repl FROM replacements )
            )
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( value )
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb7d7c/1/2)**:

```
| DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(VALUE) |
|---------------------------|
|                    (null) |
|                         0 |
|                        10 |
|                     40000 |
|                     40400 |
|                     40400 |
|                     40400 |
|                     44000 |
|                     44000 |
|                     44000 |
|                     80000 |
|                     80000 |
|                     80000 |
```

Comment: Nice work. Tests successfully. In my tests on an Exadata machine running 12.1.0.2 it's a little slower. To do all the updates 10 times in a loop with `lob_replace` took `1.161 1.278 1.298` seconds; `replace_with_clob` took `0.749 0.962 0.838` seconds. Would be interesting to compare performance on 11g.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
function CLOBREPLACE(
  AINPUT      CLOB,
  APATTERN    VARCHAR2,
  ASUBSTITUTE CLOB
) return CLOB is
FCLOB   CLOB := AINPUT;
FOFFSET INTEGER;
FCHUNK  CLOB;
begin
  if length(ASUBSTITUTE) > 32000 then
    FOFFSET := 1;
    FCLOB := replace(FCLOB, APATTERN, '###CLOBREPLACE###');
    while FOFFSET <= length(ASUBSTITUTE) loop
      FCHUNK := substr(ASUBSTITUTE, FOFFSET, 32000) || '###CLOBREPLACE###';
      FCLOB := regexp_replace(FCLOB, '###CLOBREPLACE###', FCHUNK);
      FOFFSET := FOFFSET + 32000;
    end loop;
    FCLOB := regexp_replace(FCLOB, '###CLOBREPLACE###', '');
  else 
    FCLOB := replace(FCLOB, APATTERN, ASUBSTITUTE);
  end if;
  return FCLOB;
end;
```

Result of test case:

```
v2:32767
cl_small:32767
cl_big[1]:65535
cl_big[2]:98301
cl_big[3]:131069
```

Comment: Sorry, have not read the question carefully. Not the complete solution.

Comment: The one problem still remains (when the result CLOB is getting big: about 1000000 bytes in my case): ORA-22926: specified trim length is greater than current LOB value's length. To avoid this the regexp_replace is used, but this can not be applied to original pattern, unless you sure it does not contain regexp characters.

Answer (score -1):

Function REPLACE can be used for CLOB

Doc:
http://psoug.org/reference/translate_replace.html

Working sample:

```
declare
  l_clob clob;
  l_parname clob;
  l_value  clob;
  l_par_id_obj        varchar2(200) := '${id_obj}';

  procedure setCLOBValue(p_CLOB in out CLOB, p_value string) as
  begin
    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(p_CLOB, false);
    dbms_lob.open(p_CLOB, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
    dbms_lob.write(p_CLOB, length(p_value), 1, p_value);
    dbms_lob.close(p_CLOB);
  end;

begin
  select SOURCE_FILE into l_clob from st_static_source_clob;

  setCLOBValue(l_parname, l_par_id_obj);
  setCLOBValue(l_value, '200701000024');

  l_clob := replace(l_clob, l_parname, l_value);

end;
```

Comment: No, your replacement value is way too small to replicate the issue that was originally raised. This question was about replacement values that are greater than 32K.

Answer (score -1):

Below function solves the problem:

```
create or replace FUNCTION replace_clob
(
  in_source  IN CLOB,
  in_search  IN VARCHAR2,
  in_replace IN CLOB
) 
RETURN CLOB 
IS
  l_pos pls_integer;
  out_replace_clob CLOB := in_source;
BEGIN
  l_pos := instr(in_source, in_search);

  IF l_pos > 0 THEN
  WHILE l_pos > 0 LOOP
    out_replace_clob := substr(out_replace_clob, 1, l_pos-1)
        || in_replace
        || substr(out_replace_clob, l_pos+LENGTH(in_search));
  l_pos := instr(out_replace_clob, in_search);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN out_replace_clob;
  END IF;

  RETURN in_source;
END replace_clob;
/
```

Comment: Nice try, although this suffers from the possibility of an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

This below function gives replace all functionality for CLOB datatype in Oracle PLSQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION lob_replaceall
(
  i_lob    IN clob, 
  i_what   IN varchar2, 
  i_with   IN clob,
  i_offset IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1
) RETURN CLOB
AS
  o_lob  CLOB;
  n      PLS_INTEGER;
  l_lob  PLS_INTEGER;
  l_what PLS_INTEGER;
  l_with PLS_INTEGER;
  l_temp_lob CLOB;
BEGIN
  IF   i_lob IS NULL
    OR i_what IS NULL
    OR i_offset < 1
    OR i_offset > DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE
  THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  l_temp_lob:=i_lob;
  LOOP 
  n      := NVL( DBMS_LOB.INSTR( l_temp_lob, i_what, i_offset, 1 ), 0 );
  l_lob  := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( l_temp_lob );
  l_what := LENGTH( i_what );
  l_with := NVL( DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( i_with ), 0 );

  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( o_lob, FALSE );
  IF n > 0 THEN
    IF n > 1 THEN
      DBMS_LOB.COPY( o_lob, l_temp_lob, n-1, 1, 1 );
    END IF;

    IF l_with > 0 THEN
      DBMS_LOB.APPEND( o_lob, i_with ); 
    END IF;

    IF n + l_what <= l_lob THEN
      DBMS_LOB.COPY( o_lob, l_temp_lob, l_lob - n - l_what + 1, n + l_with, n + l_what );
    END IF;
  ELSE
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND( o_lob, l_temp_lob );
  END IF;
  EXIT WHEN n=0;
  l_temp_lob:= o_lob;
  o_lob := NULL;
 END LOOP;
  RETURN o_lob;
END; 
/
```

Comment: Hi @Jeffery Kemp... I agree i have copied.. I just enhanced the functionality with replace all... In my requirement i just needed replace all.. I pasted the code here so that someone can use without any modification

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice you had done that. It's no problem to take someone's work to adapt it, but it's good form to acknowledge their work when you do. In this case it's not a bad solution I think. Perhaps if possible avoid putting createTemporary within the loop. I haven't tried this but I suspect a performance issue might occur if there are a lot of replacements to be done, due to all the copying and temp space needed. But that's not always a big concern depending on the requirements.