# Convert LISTAGG to XMLAGG

Tags: oracle, string-concatenation, listagg, xmlelement

I have a query using LISTAGG function that need to convert to XMLAGG in order to handle string concatenation more than 4000 characters:

```
 LISTAGG(NAME || INPUT || DESC || ' ' || '<cm>' || DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NAME) AS ENTRIES
```

I try the following:

```
REPLACE(
 REPLACE(
    XMLAGG(
       XMLELEMENT("A",NAME|| INPUT || DESC || ' ' || '<cm>' || DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10) ORDER BY NAME).getClobaVal(),<A>',''),
   '</A>','[delimiter]') AS ENTRIES
```

The syntax error encountered at ORDER BY

Comment: there are missing `)` before `ORDER BY ` and `'` => `<A>','''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed )
Try please:

```
XMLAGG(
         XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME)
```

Comment: I try with same xmlagg. Look can help you: EXTRACT (XMLAGG(
         XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME)
        , 'X/text()').getstringval()

Comment: fixed the syntax error, but runtime error encountered
ORA-00904: "SYS"."XMLTYPE"."GETCLOBAVAL": invalid identifier

Comment: try XMLAGG(
        XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME).extract('X/text()').getclobval()

Comment: typo fixed,another error on the line of second REPLACE(
ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function

Comment: full statement:
REPLACE(
 REPLACE(
    XMLAGG(
        XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME).extract('X/text()').getClobVal()),'<A>',''),
   '</A>','[delimiter])' AS MATCH_ENTRIES

Comment: Try:  REPLACE( REPLACE( 
 XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME).extract('X/text()').getClobVal()
 ,'<A>',''), '</A>','[delimiter])')

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
there has no CLOB datatype in my DB column, those field names in concatenation are all in VARCHAR2

Comment: It's error for replace to clob. show this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126455/how-to-call-replace-with-clob-without-exceeding-32k

Comment: i tried to do substr the clob and convert it to CHAR:
TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(REPLACE( REPLACE( XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME).extract('X/text()').getClobVal(),1,4000)),'<A>',''), '</A>','[delimiter])') AS MATCH_ENTRIES

Another error: ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function

Comment: try this REPLACE( REPLACE( 
 TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT ("X", FIELD_NAME|| INPUT || DESCRIPTION_KEY || ' ' || '<cm>' || MATCH_DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10)) ORDER BY FIELD_NAME).extract('X/text()').getClobVal(),1,4000))
 ,'<A>',''), '</A>','[delimiter])')

Comment: You are welcome. Confirm, please, my answer as rigth.

Answer (score 0):

You missed "**)**" and  " **'** "

**Try this:**

```
REPLACE(
 REPLACE(
    XMLAGG(
       XMLELEMENT("A",NAME|| INPUT || DESC || ' ' || '<cm>' || DATA || '</cm>', CHR(13)||CHR(10) ORDER BY NAME).getClobaVal()),'<A>',''),
   '</A>','[delimiter]') AS ENTRIES
```